# Making changes to MOVIE list MVC tutorial - Adding a new partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, partial-views

I am following this tutorial to learn basic MVC  [Movie List Tutorial in MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs) I am at the end of the tutorial. Now I want to do my own modification to this tutorial. First, I want to add a new partial view to this movie list view. So in a DIV, I put the following code in the index page that already renders the movie list.

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_NewPartialView");}
```

For this to work, first in the Models folder, I create a new model class for NewClass.cs. The model folder already has a Movie Model Class.Movie.cs 
Question1 : Should I be creating a separate Model .cs file for the new partial view or Should I create additional classes in the same Movie.cs file?

Then I created a partial view using scaffolding based on the new Model (for now I have the new model in a separate .cs file - meaning I now have two Models one for Movies and one for the NewModel (for partialview).  I want this rendered in the original movie list index page as a partial view on the side.

I have a MoviesController that has the code

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }
```

Am I missing anything else? If I try to run this, it is breaking at the line of code

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_NewPartialView");}
```

and the error message I get at this point of the code is "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Movie]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.NewModel]'.

I need some MVC expert guidance in this step of adding a new partial view based on a new model to an existing View/Model. I need help and appreciate any tid bits of information that will help me learn. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error message your view is expecting an `IEnumerable` which contains classes of `Project.Models.NewModel` where as your passing a `List` containing classes of `Project.Models.Movie`. Basically your passing your view data it's not designed to deal with. You can either change your view/partial at the top to read something like:

```
@model List<Project.Models.Movie>
```

This sets you view to expect a list of moives which is what your passing your view from your controller in the example. On a side note

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Movie>
```

would work as well as a `List` inherits from IEnumerable.

If you want the view to accept an `IEnumerable<Project.Models.NewModel>` then you need to modify your controller to something like: (I'm making assumptions about your model properties here)

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Movies.Select(m => new NewModel { Title = m.Title, Director = m.Director}));
}
```

This will then pass an `IEnumerable<Project.Models.NewModel>` to you view.

On another note a simpler way to reference partials in razor is:

```
@Html.Partial("_NewPartialView")
```

### Update

You need to create yourself a `ViewModel` so it will look something like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
  public List<Movie> Movies {get; set;}
  public List<NewModel> NewModels {get; set;}
}

public ViewResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel
    {
      Movies = db.Movies.ToList(),
      NewModels = new List<NewModel>() // Or however you populate it
    };

    return View(viewModel );
}
```

Then in your view it will be something like this for your movies

```
@foreach (var moive in Model.Movies) { }
```

and you new model partials will be

```
@Html.Partial("_NewPartialView", Model.NewModels)
```

Note you will need to update your model at the top of the index page to reference IndexViewModel.

Comment: " You can either change your view/partial at the top to read something like:

@model List<Project.Models.Movie>"  But the new partial view is not based on the movie model.. it is something else.. lets say, TVShows (new model)

Comment: May be I was not clear enough.. Its two different things I want on the Index.cshtml... based on two models..one existing Movie.cs model and the other NewModel.cs....The Index page already has a list of movies view... I want to add a new list (partialview) based on a completely different model , .cs file class. If I do what you suggest in the second option... changing the ViewResult Index() .. how will I accomplish both views...in the same page..

Comment: ok but in your controller your passing the view a list of movies, thats the problem. In your controller you need to pass the view the correct type, in your example tvshows

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now.. thank you. I will try this out in a few minutes and get back to you. Again appreciate your help.

Comment: The IndexView Model- is it going to be needing its own .cs file or part of Movie or NewModel .cs files? or is it just added in the controller?... thinking about referencing it.. your last comment line.

Comment: I would put it in its own cs file in the models directory.

Comment: You Wrote --- "Then in your view it will be something like this for your movies

@foreach (var moive in Model.Movies) { }
and you new model partials will be

@Html.Partial("_NewPartialView", Model.NewModels)" But I am not able to get intellisense recognize Model.Movies and Model.NewModels .. did I miss anything... I added a new model IndexViewModel in in its own .cs file. I referenced the new model in both index.cshtml and partialview.cshtml pages... I changed the action where its rendering view according to your suggestion...

Comment: I made the following changes to the IndexViewModel .. added two lines to your code.     public class IndexViewModel
    {
            public List<Movie> Movies{ get; set; }
            public List<TVShow> TvShows{ get; set; }


            public Movie Movie{ get; set; }
            public TvShow TvShow{ get; set; }
    } now the intellisense works in the index.cshtml page and i can add @foreach (var moive in Model.Movies) { } easily.. now.

Comment: Please see the update in your first post.... for complete post of mine in response to your solution.. thank you

Comment: Have you thought about using an EditorFor helper or DisplayFor? MVC makes it incredibly simple to encapsulate enumerable classes. The properties would still be on the model of course as an IEnumerable<Movie>. Generally speaking having your models contain public complex pbjects is a bad idea. The model should represent the view entirely. Meaning, if you have a partial then there should be a corresponding POCO model for every input. The model must then have a function to convert it to the complex object type, then perform the action.